Inequality on Sobolev norm
I have a problem with the following inequality. Suppose r and r' are Holder conjugate, i.e. $\frac{1}{r} + \frac{1}{r'} = 1$. Then we have
$$|||u|^{\alpha -1} u||_{W^{1, r'}(\mathbb{R}^n )} \leq c ||u||_{L^r(\mathbb{R}^n)}^{\alpha -1} ||u||_{W^{1, r}(\mathbb{R}^n)}.$$
I tried with the standard Holder inequality but I failed. Can someone help me, please?

Can You tell something about the possible values of $\alpha$?

I have the conditions: $1 < \alpha < \frac{n+2}{n-2}$ and $\alpha > 1 + \frac{4}{n}$ for $n \geq 3$.

One proof of special case is given here. Suppose $u\in W^{1,r}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $r>2$, by Holder inequality, we have
$$
  \left\| |u|^{\alpha-1}u \right\|_{L^{r'}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\le \left\| |u|^{\alpha-1} \right\|_{L^s(\mathbb{R}^n)}\cdot \left\|u\right\|_{L^t((\mathbb{R}^n))} = \left\| u \right\|_{L^{s(\alpha-1)}(\mathbb{R}^n)}^{\alpha-1}\cdot \left\|u\right\|_{L^t((\mathbb{R}^n))},\qquad (1)
$$
where $\frac{1}{r'} = \frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{t}$. Since $\left|\nabla (|u|^{\alpha-1}u)\right| \le \alpha |u|^{\alpha-1} \cdot \left|\nabla u\right|$, one gets
$$
  \left\| \nabla (|u|^{\alpha-1}u) \right\|\le \alpha\left\| u \right\|_{L^{s(\alpha-1)}(\mathbb{R}^n)}^{\alpha-1}\cdot \left\| \nabla u \right\|_{L^t((\mathbb{R}^n))}.\qquad (2)
$$
By $(1)$ and $(2)$, there holds
$$
  \left\| |u|^{\alpha-1}u \right\|_{W^{1,r'}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\le (1+\alpha)\left\| u \right\|_{L^{s(\alpha-1)}(\mathbb{R}^n)}^{\alpha-1}\cdot \left\| \nabla u \right\|_{W^{1,t}((\mathbb{R}^n))}.\qquad (3)
$$
Comparing (3) and the inequality in this question, we take $s(\alpha-1)=r$ and $t=r$, then
$$
  \frac{1}{r'}=\frac{r-1}{r} = \frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{t} = \frac{\alpha-1}{r} + \frac{1}{r} = \frac{\alpha}{r}.
$$
It yields
$$
  \alpha = r-1.
$$
Hence, the following inequality holds
$$
  \left\| |u|^{\alpha-1}u \right\|_{W^{1,r'}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\le (1+\alpha)\left\| u \right\|_{L^{r}(\mathbb{R}^n)}^{\alpha-1}\cdot \left\| \nabla u \right\|_{W^{1,r}((\mathbb{R}^n))},\quad \alpha=r-1,\qquad (4)
$$
for $r>2$. Indeed, if $r=2$, it is easy to check the inequality $(4)$.

Thank you so much!
